# R RDSTK::street2coordinates failed to connect

Tags: r

I have no success with the following R codes:

```
data <- c("1208 Buckingham Drive, Crystal Lake, IL 60014",
+           "9820 State Street East, Paducah, KY 42001",
+           "685 Park Place, Saint Petersburg, FL 33702",
+           "5316 4th Avenue, Charlotte, NC 28205",
+           "2994 Somerset Drive, Baldwinsville, NY 13027",
+           "5457 5th Street South, Tallahassee, FL 32303")

geocode  <- do.call(rbind, lapply(data, street2coordinates))
```

the error message says:

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :
Failed to connect to [www.datasciencetoolkit.org](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org) port 80: Operation timed out

Is this some setup issue in my RStudio?  Thanks for help!

Comment: I don't recommending using this old, unmaintained package (it has some problematic dependencies, like the retired `plyr` package). Does this approach look viable to you?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887833/r-how-to-geocode-a-simple-address-using-data-science-toolbox

Comment: I am still getting "timed out" error.  Not sure what went wrong.